# How to find output of ideal op-amp system?

Tags: operational-amplifier, dc

[image]

[edited the picture]

I have the op-amp system like this. I've just learnt how to apply the characteristic of each O-A for finding the output (using the given Av formula for inverted amplifier or integrator O-A). But for this we just can assume the O-A is ideal and have to find the output voltage.

Do you guy have any idea how to do this, I had failed to do this in my exam this afternoon and feeling curious about this...

Comment: Two rules: 1) When there is a negative feedback, the voltage on `-` equals to the voltage on `+`. 2) There is no current to/from the opamp inputs. These two should be enough to solve this circuit.

Comment: So we just solve for Vo of each op-amp and then apply KVL KCL etc right :D

Comment: but I don't know why there are R4 in the bottom, I thought that we can go through R2 to Vo... @EugeneSh.

Comment: Just apply the rules above to this circuit and write down the currents and voltages in terms of each other. As an example, the current through R3 and R4 is the same and equals to `(Vo-Vx)/R4` *AND* to `Vx/R3`, while Vx is the voltage on the `+` *AND* `-` terminal of the left OPAMP.

Comment: Can you post a clearer picture?  The + and - terminals on the amps are unreadable.

Comment: yeah I repost the picture @JRE

Comment: @EugeneSh. I am currently have the output voltage of left O-A is -2Vi but stuck in the entrance of the second O-A. I think I will do V+ = V- and find the output voltage of second O-A but I don't know how to find the current go through 2 resistor R6 and R7

Comment: You should probably think about this problem like a _feedback control system_ type of problem. That might make the math easier for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a good problem because you actually have to *think* to solve it.  +1 to your professor.

It's hard to see, but I'm assuming the negative inputs of the opamps are at top, and the positive ones at bottom.

The first thing to do is to look at the overall topology and what is going on.  You should immediately see that the first opamp by itself is a inverting amplifier, and the second a non-inverting amplifier.

The gains should also be obvious if you know anything about basic opamp circuits.  The first one has a gain of -2, and the second of 3.  Therefore, without the global feedback, the two-opamp chain has a gain of -6.

Now consider what happens when some positive feedback is added around a amplifier.  Surely *hysteresis* was covered in your class.  You should be able to see what the two hysteresis thresholds are.  Once you know those, you can make a plot of input voltage as a function of output voltage.

Since these are ideal opamps, assume the output goes fully to one power rail or the other when the two inputs aren't equal.